# Script to check and not to copy same file

Tags: batch-file

My scheduler will run every 15 mins and I don’t want to copy the same file again.

I have the script below in a batch file running in the task scheduler:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP

FOR /R C:\Utils\TRASACTION\ICP %%f IN (*.LOG) DO TYPE NUL>%%f

Winscp.com /script=C:\Utils\TRASACTION\ICPS\download.txt >> C:\Utils\ICPS\lowe.log

set CURRENT_DATE=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%

xcopy C:\Utils\TRASACTION\Accounting_file\%CURRENT_DATE%\ACCOUNTING_FILE_* Y:\Transactions\In >> C:\Utils\TRASACTION\ICPS\lowe.log

exit
```

in line 3 that download.txt contains the below script

```
option echo off 
option batch on 
option confirm off 

open sftp://icps:xxxxxxxxx@11.111.111.111

lcd "C:\Utils\ TRASACTION\ICPS"

cd /Out/1.ACCOUNTINGFILE

get %TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd% C:\Utils\ TRASACTION\Accounting_file\
exit
```

I would like to insert a check in the script when the folder is available then proceed to the copy or else exit.

Or is there another way not the copy the file from the folder that has been already copied to the directory in below line?

```
(xcopy C:\Utils\TRASACTION\Accounting_file\%CURRENT_DATE%\ACCOUNTING_FILE_* Y:\Transactions\In >> C:\Utils\TRASACTION\ICPS\lowe.log
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you format the post to use code blocks instead of just copying and pasting a bunch of lines

Comment: sorry.Formatting done

Comment: You can use the `IF EXIST` command in a batch file to check for the existence of a file or folder.

Comment: Why do you download the file to `C:` first and only move it to `Y:` afterwards? Why don't you synchronize the remote folder against `Y:` straight away?